# Is there a way to declare a pointer in a header file and instantiate it in a .cpp?

Tags: c++, pointers

Exactly as my question reads:
   Is there a way to declare a pointer in a header file and instantiate it in a .cpp?

I have this so far:

.h:

```
FILE* stream;
```

.cpp

```
stream = fopen("com2", "r");
```

But this give me this error:

> 1>gpsHandler.obj : error LNK2001:
>   unresolved external symbol "struct
>   _iobuf * stream" (?stream@@3PAU_iobuf@@A)
>   1>C:\Users***\portReading\Debug\portReading.exe
>   : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved
>   externals

Comment: Have you included header file in your .cpp?

Comment: While what your are doing is incorrect, the error message you posted is still inconsistent with the "code" you posted. Edit your post. What's the name of .h file? What's the name of .cpp file? Is the former included into the latter? What file is `gpsHandler`?

Answer (score 5):

As long as the variable in the source file is not `static` (internal linkage), you can declare the variable in a header file with `extern FILE* stream;`. This is how we declare global variables:

.h:

```
extern FILE* stream;
```

.cpp:

```
FILE* stream;
```

As far as your error is concerned, you probably need to `#include <cstdio>`

Answer (score 1):

try declare it as `extern FILE* straem;` in header file?